# Python 2.7 sub process

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, subprocess, flopy

I have a python script that uses a package called flopy.  My script generates a series of inputs to a fortran executable.  Flopy writes these into text files and then calls the fortran executable, which uses the text files to run a model.

I'm using a mac (OSX) and I downloaded python 2.7 from python.org- i.e. I'm not using the Apple system version of python.  The version of python I'm using is in Library/Frameworks/Python.Frameworks/

I can run my script if I call it from the Terminal window (by typing:

```
Python myscriptname.py
```

However if I run my script through IDLE (the version that came with python which I downloaded it) it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/neilthomas/RotatedModel_v4_Tr_mfnwt.py", line 355, in <module>
    success, mfoutput = mf.run_model(silent=False, pause=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flopy/mbase.py", line 638, in run_model
normal_msg=normal_msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flopy/mbase.py", line 1034, in run_model
stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, cwd=model_ws)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The file 'mfnwt' absolutely does exist.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but is there something I need to do to allow IDLE to run programs/subprocesses via the shell it uses?  Thanks.

Comment: "The file 'mfnwt' absolutely does exist"...Are you sure?

Comment: How did you run idle? And do you use a relative file name? Your current working directory may not be what you think it is and that will affect relative path names. Print `os.getcwd()` to see what it is.

Comment: @Rishav: Yes, the file mfnwt does exist- as noted above, I can run the same script through Terminal.

Comment: @tdelaney: I run IDLE by right clicking on the script and opening the python script with IDLE.  The script is in the same file directory as the file 'mfnwt'.

Comment: I don't know about OSX specifically, but right-clicking doesn't usually set the current directory. Try right-clicking a simple script like `import os;print(os.getcwd());input("end")` to see what it is.

Comment: When you right click, do you `edit with IDLE` and then run either with IDLE's `Run` menu or the`F5` shortcut, or do actually `run` from the context menu?  In either case, the traceback says you are running "/Users/neilthomas/RotatedModel_v4_Tr_mfnwt.py".  Is this correct?  Which patch release of 2.7 did you download?  The current one, about a month ago, is 2.7.13 and I would recommend that.

Comment: The line numbers in my copy of the 2.7.13 version of subprocess.py are about 300 less than in the traceback.  That is why I think you are running an older version.  What I understand from the traceback is that IDLE ran your program, which called flopy.mbase.run_model, which called subprocess.??? to run 'something' in a subprocess.  There was an error in either the child part of subprocess.POpen._execute_child or in the 'something' itself when executed in the child process.  This is reported as an OSError, which you believe is connected with a file called 'mfnwt'. (see next comment)

Comment: From my reading of _execute_child, the `child_exception` raised should have a `child_traceback` attribute, which was not printed.  I would want to see it.  To do so, I would try the following in the original program, which where it calls run_model: `try: <failing call to run_model>\nexcept OSError as e: print(e.child_traceback)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have to identify the specific MODFLOW executable file you are calling ('mfnwt' in your case). I do the same with a MODFLOW 2000 file:

```
mf = flopy.modflow.mf.Modflow(modelname,namefile_ext='nam',version='mf2k',exe_name='/home/MODFLOW-and-related-codes/build-08/bin-windows/mf2k.exe')
```

In your case, you would do something similar, only replacing the `version='mf2k'` and `exe_name=path` to match where you are storing your MODFLOW file.

See the documentation for further details: https://modflowpy.github.io/flopydoc/mf.html